# How do I get the drive letter a batch script is running from?

Tags: scripting, batch-file, drive

I have a batch script on a CD. Whenever I try to run it and enter `%~d0`, it returns the C: drive instead of F:, which is my CD drive.

What is a way to find the drive letter?

Comment: What is the exact command that uses `%~d0`?

Answer (score 26):

Get the drive letter from the current directory with:

```
%cd:~0,2%
```

%~dp0 is pretty useful in a bat: it is the folder in which the executing bat file resides.

Perhaps at the top of your script, do something like:

```
set _SCRIPT_DRIVE=%~d0
set _SCRIPT_PATH=%~p0
```

and then echo it out to debug. %~d0 should be giving you what you want, but the other options I mentioned might be helpful in solving the challenge.

Comment: Doesn't %cd% give the path you are _executing_ from, though? It is completely inaccurate for getting the actual batch file's path. For example, Windows XP seems to have the bizarre bug that if you drag and drop a file onto a program/script to give that dropped file as argument to the program to execute, the program will mysteriously launch from the c:\Documents and Settings\\(username) directory instead of from its own folder.

Comment: Seems it changed since XP, but in Win7 it seems to execute from the path of the parameter file instead... which is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%~dp0` to get the current/working directory:

```
%~d0
```